# Custom View add SubView layout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, layout

There is a tableView with 2 sections, which have a **customized** section header **view** for each.

I want UI of this effect, and header view of section **0** works fine.

[image: what wrong]

### While header view of section 1 has an issue.

I don't know what's wrong.

### What Apple mechanism do I miss,

`convert rect/point`?

[image: logic is wrong]

Here is the code:
the **customized** **view** of section **1**

```
@interface ZBWithDrawHeaderView()
     @property (nonatomic, strong ) UIView *renderView;
 @end
@implementation ZBWithDrawHeaderView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor ];

        _renderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, KScreenWidth, -17)];
       //it works OK, I don't know the logic.

      //  _renderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, KScreenWidth, 17)];
      //it works Wrong ,what mechanism do I miss

        [self addSubview: _renderView];
        _renderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor ];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Where I put it into use?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   if(section == 0){
         ......
         return view;
   }
    else if (section == 1) {
        ZBWithDrawHeaderView * secondHeaderView = [[ZBWithDrawHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, KScreenWidth, 25)];
        return secondHeaderView;
    }
    return nil;
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? When i see you picture, i can't know where is your header and what happens with it.

Comment: Thank you  @trungduc . When I try to make a better demo, I add two UITableViewDelegate Methods `tableView: viewForFooterInSection:` `tableView heightForFooterInSection:` , It works perfectly.  I thought `sectionFooterView `can be avoided originally .since I don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return [UIView new ];
}
```

The two `UITableViewDelegate` methods added, no strange layout happens. Seems like section header and footer must come in pair.